# Representation of pairs in System F

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming, haskell, polymorphisms

System F defines the data type pair as:
$$X\times Y := \Pi Z. (X\to Y \to Z)\to Z$$
with:
$$\langle x,y \rangle := \Lambda Z. \lambda p^{X\to Y\to Z}.p \text{ }x\text{ } y$$
Projections are defined:
$$\pi^1 p := pX(\lambda x^X.\lambda y^Y.x)$$
$$\pi^2 p := pY(\lambda x^X.\lambda y^Y.y)$$

It is easy to prove that:
$$\pi^1 \langle x,y \rangle=x$$
$$\pi^2 \langle x,y \rangle=y$$
But I do not know how to prove the following
$$\langle \pi^1 p, \pi^2 p\rangle=p$$

I suppose that I will need the parametricity theorem...

Comment: Yes, indeed you do.

Comment: Could you provide me with proof?

Comment: https://hub.darcs.net/dolio/agda-share/browse/ParamInduction.agda#130

Comment: I appreciate your response very much. However, I don’t know Agda or Coq. Could you provide me with a “verbal” demonstration?